# Manipulation jar file at runtime

Tags: java, jar, wso2

I'm trying to change my `Java` code at runtime inside my `.jar` file. When I put my .jar file inside `wso2ei-6.4.0\lib` before running up. This way is working fine but when I try to change my .jar file wso2 still gets my old class inside jar. Here my codes:

```
package com.Sample.Sample;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class Sample extends AbstractMediator { 

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Sample.class);
    private String name;

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        // TODO Implement your mediation logic here
        printTheName(context);
        return true;
    }

    private void printTheName(MessageContext context){

        String getNameFromSQ = (String)context.getProperty("NAME");
        log.debug("Name Value: " + getNameFromSQ);
        String upCaseName = getNameFromSQ.toUpperCase();
        context.setProperty("newName", "Logging newName new new:" + upCaseName);
    }

    public void setPrintTheName(String newName){
        this.name=newName;
    }

    public String getPrintTheName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

My SQ:

```
<property name="NAME" value= "Kerem"/>
    <class name="com.Sample.Sample.Sample">
        <property name="printTheName" value= "Log from SQ"/>
    </class>

    <log>
           <property name="newName" expression="get-property('newName')"/>
    </log>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

When you put .jar in `<product home>`/lib it will be copied to `<product home>`/dropins directory automatically when you start the server. If you want to new artifacts be affected please remove old corresponding artifact from `<product home>`/dropins as well.

Comment: I both changed `/lib` and `/dropins` at runtime. There was nothing. When I did this, I checked my new jar file, my .class updated but Wso2 run old one.

Comment: delete old one from both places /lib and /dropins. Copy new one to /lib only. Restart the server

Comment: my aim is manipulation at runtime. I figured out running when i put `/lib` and restarted. I need manipulate at runtime because my prod env. :) Any suggestion?

Comment: production can't be interrupt only for this.

Comment: actually, https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Uploading+Artifacts this is what i'm looking for but my all env is running at wso2-ei-6.4.0 not wso2-ei-6.1.1